# How to iterate through, and update each element of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable object that has been populated by an SqlQuery call and I want to iterarate through it and update its type class members.

My example code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

...

public JsonResult GetMyClass(...)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> oMyClass = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("SELECT ...");

    // Here I want to iterate through the oMyClass object updating
    // the "data" member before returning it as a Json

    return Json(oMyClass, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a nice way of doing this, expecially if one also want to update the object and not just reading from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `foreach`. That's what it is there for:

```
foreach(var item in oMyClass)
{
    item.Property = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, that's why I thought it had to be done differently.  Knowing that foreach does this is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetMyClass(...)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> oMyClass = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("SELECT ...");

    foreach (var o in oMyClass)
    {
        // do somethig with o
    }

    return Json(oMyClass, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> oMyClass = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("SELECT ...").ToList();
oMyClass.ForEach(i => i.data = somevalue);
```